# comparing values in two dataframes and returning differences

Tags: r, dataframe, diff

I would like to compare two data frames in order to find the delta values by 'Group'. There are instances where the first data frame may have a 'Group' that the other does not. In those cases, the result should reflect the value shown.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Group = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
              Month.1 = c(10,15,30,24,16,33,27,19),
              Month.2 = c(20,37,12,31,26,22,31,20))

df2 <- data.frame(Group = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"),
              Month.1 = c(12,25,34,24,21,30,22),
              Month.2 = c(28,40,36,32,26,17,25))
```

I'm not really sure how to solve this problem. I've explored using setdiff, but that only returns the original values, not the difference.

The result should be as follows:

```
result <- data.frame(Group = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
                 Month.1 = c(2,10,4,0,5,-3,-5,19),
                 Month.2 = c(8,3,24,1,0,-5,-6,20))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do a `full_join` on `df1` and `df2`, `group_by` `Group` and take the difference between values. (Thanks to @Onyambu for suggesting this approach)

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2) %>%
   group_by(Group) %>%
   summarise_all(~if(n() > 1) diff(.) else .)

#  Group Month.1 Month.2
#  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A           2       8
#2 B          10       3
#3 C           4      24
#4 D           0       1
#5 E           5       0
#6 F          -3      -5
#7 G          -5      -6
#8 H          19      20
```

which in base R is

```
aggregate(.~Group, merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE), function(x) 
          if(length(x) > 1) diff(x) else x)
```

Comment: instead of just having `all.x=TRUE` you should consider `all=TRUE` since there can be a row in df2 that is not in df1

Comment: @Onyambu You are correct. I have changed my answer to use `full_join` instead of `left_join`.